# Swiper throws error on destroying swiper every time after the first time

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

Right now I have a Swiper that is created when a 'popup' is created. (Not an actual separate window, just a modal) Inside of this swiper is two other swipers that control each other, and a button to close the window.

When the outer swiper goes to the next slide, it destroys the old two sliders and makes a new one. It does this fine over and over again.

However the issue is when the main wrapper swiper is destroyed anytime beyond the first time.

I think Swiper might just have a hard time handling looped slides, or I'm doing it wrong.

I had to move this

```
$('.destroy').click(function() {
    mySwiper.destroy();
});
```

into it's own function like

```
var destroySlider = function() {
  $('.destroy').click(function() {
    mySwiper.destroy();
  });
}
```

and then call it from where the slider is initialized, because if I just had it on it's own, the destroy buttons on the duplicate slides created by having it loop didn't function at all. So now I moved it into it's own named function and call then on swiper initalization.. which works fine but throws a console error every time the slider is destroyed beyond the first destroy.

The error is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detachEvents' of null

Here is a (dis-)functioning fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/38yftqvb/2/